# Where is Marceno's missing crate?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm doing the "All Hands on Deck" quest, but I can't find the crate anywhere in Ondra's gift. Where exactly is that chest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chest is located in the area marked by red circle.

[image: Ondra's gift]

In case you're wondering how I found it, in the green circles I have marked the locations of two NPCs whom I asked for directions. One in the center pointed `East` and shady merchant in the east prompted me to go `South`.

Comment: It was exactly where you marked it, so it's unlikely to be random

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for feedback, I edited the answer to get rid of that guesswork.